# Como fixar um TextBox em cada página no SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Olá.

Estou desenvolvendo um relatório no qual consta o nome da pessoa e uma tabela com as informações dela. Está organizado de maneira que o nome fique em cima da tabela.

```
Nome: Fulano

Dado1 | Dado2 | Dado3
---------------------
aaaa  | bbbbb | cccc
aaaa  | bbbbb | cccc
aaaa  | bbbbb | cccc
```

Quando tem muitas informações na tabela ela é continuada na próxima página, ai que está o desafio. Quero fazer aparecer o nome da pessoa nessa página. Algo parecido com o header.
Existe alguma maneira de fixar o textbox para cada página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução que eu precisava.

No corpo do relatório adicionei uma List dentro dessa List adicionei uma Table.

Mantendo a List selecionada, no campo abaixo Row Groups alterei as propriedades

> Group Proprerties > General > Add > Referenciar o código para a quebra

Feito isso, vou a minha tabela. Ativo o *Modo Avançado*:

> Ao lado de Column Groups tem uma seta apontando para baixo

Com isso deverá abilitar o modo estático (Static). Clique no primeiro Static e precione F4 para abrir as propriedades. No conjunto outros (Others):

> KeepWithGroup mude para After
>
> RepeatOnNewPage mude para True

Com isso feito, clique na lateral esquerda do Header da sua Tabela e adiciona uma nova linha superior, assim essa nova linha estará presente em todas as páginas.